# Items show up as blank spaces when trading with friend over steam

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Playing Team Fortress 2 Premium, I am trying to send my friend a Pip-boy, for the engineer. For some reason, hey can not receive items for Team Fortress 2.

He can receive Steam Trading Cards, and games, but when I drag a Team Fortress 2 item into the trade, all it appears as is a blank space. My friend also sees nothing. How do we fix this?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Will it show in the trading inventory but not trade, or is it not even there? Please explain

Comment: I'll drag the item to the trading box and the item will not appear but a blank space appears instead. on his end he can't see the item at all.

Comment: Well I'm not enterally sure, maybe you need to restart your steam but I'm not sure, sorry :/

Comment: Does the item have a `Non-tradable` tag on it? Also, may I have a look at your inventory? ([Link?](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aytimothy/inventory)) or at least a picture of you being unable to drag it into the trade window? Also, have you tried double-clicking the item while in the trade window instead of dragging?

Comment: Maybe try to refresh the page with F5 when it doesn't work? Sometimes my trades bug out and refreshing fixes them.

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/id/Yarharfiddlydee is my steam profile. i tried re inviting him to trade but it didnt work. i should bring up that he is f2p but he should still be able to recieve items right?

Comment: also i have tried the double clicking it does not work

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common side effect when trading servers are experiencing issues (which is quite frequently).

If you're dragging stuff over to your trade window or double clicking on items and it's not responding by putting that item in the trade window, give it a few minutes/hours/other arbitrary time period and try again.